# Problems with internet permission in android

Tags: android

everyone!!! I have got some little problem with internet permission in my android application. I have defined the permission in AndroidManifest.xml , but when I start my application, I don`t get data from internet. This is IOException tag from my LogCat:

12-16 10:08:57.736: DEBUG/IOException(281): Permission denied (maybe missing INTERNET permission)

Can anybody help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you please post your manifest file here?

Answer (score 3):

EDIT:
Well, I misread your post. Sorry for that.

Be sure to define the `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`
inside the `<manifest>` tag, but outside of the `<application>` tag.